# A clean way to loop HTMLWebpackPlugin with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using Webpack 4 with the HTMLWebPackPlugin.  I'm currently at the point where I am dealing with close to 30 different pages and more moving forward.  Here is a sample of what I have in code...

```
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/game11/index.html',
            mViewPort: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0',
            favicon: './src/game11/media/favicon-16x16.png',
            title: 'Game 11 Training',
            filename: 'game11.htm',
            chunks: ['game11']
        }),
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/game12/index.html',
            mViewPort: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0',
            favicon: './src/game12/media/favicon-16x16.png',
            title: 'Game 12 Training',
            filename: 'game12.htm',
            chunks: ['game12']
        }),
```

I have 30 of these so far in my webpack.config.js file.  But I would prefer to do something like this instead...

```
 ['game11','game12','something-else','etc'].forEach((event) => {
       new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
           template: './src/${event}/index.html',
           mViewPort: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0',
           favicon: './src/${event}/media/favicon-16x16.png',
           title: '${event} Training',
           filename: '${event}.htm',
           chunks: ['${event}']
       }),
   }),
```

The above code does not work and it only a sketch.  But is it possible to do something like that today without adding additional plugins or modifying my outputs?  I simply want to add array values which will create a new instance in itself.

Many thanks!

Comment: From your idea, you could use `Array.prototype.map` instead: `['game11','game12','something-else','etc'].map((event) => {
       return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({...`

Comment: love it!!! I didn't know that existed.  But even if I used it, how would I handle having comma-separated instances in a loop process.  That's one of things I don't know how to handle yet...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the same logic you suggested on your question, you could use `map` instead of `forEach` to build the plugins array like so:

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  plugins: [
    new MiniCSSExtractPlugin(),
    ...['game11', 'game12', 'something-else', 'etc'].map((event) => {
      return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: `./src/${event}/index.html`,
        mViewPort: `width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0`,
        favicon: `./src/${event}/media/favicon-16x16.png`,
        title: `${event} Training`,
        filename: `${event}.htm`,
        chunks: [`${event}`]
      })
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: when i run npm start, I get the following error from the terminal - "Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema...."

Comment: Thanks for the update! With that setup, how do i also include new MiniCSSExtractPlugin(), and new webpack.ProvidePlugin() as additional plugins?

Comment: @klewis sorry, I had an extra `[]` around the plugin

Comment: ok! I think it should work now! unless your node version doesn't support `...` spread operator, let me know if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks for not giving up on me bro.  It's now having trouble understanding ${event}. I wonder if there is a setting in webpack to enable Template Literals.  But I was able to use the classic notation of plus sign and variable name for now, and it works!

Comment: I didn't know about the 3 dot notation, thanks for bringing that up too!

Comment: You have to use `\`` instead of `'` to make `${event}` work, I fixed that too

Comment: I owe you steak next time you come to Indianapolis!  Many thanks!